# what does $\exists \varepsilon>0, \ \ F_X(t+\varepsilon) \leq F_X(t-\varepsilon)$ imply

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given $X$ random variable with the given distribution function $F_X(t)$. given that $$\exists \varepsilon>0, \ \ F_X(t+\varepsilon) \leq F_X(t-\varepsilon)$$

what is true for sure from the following:

A.$\ \mathbb{P}[X=t]=0$

B. $\ \forall \varepsilon>0, \ \ F_X(t)\geq F_X(t-\varepsilon)+\frac12$

C.  $0<t<1$

D. $\ \mathbb{P}[X>t]=0$

I dont understand how the given can help me to infer something, I would like for a small hint how do I even start to approach this problem

Comment: Can you infer something about $F_X(t+\epsilon)$ and $F_X(t-\epsilon)$ if $P[X=t]>0$?

Comment: Can you rewrite the left-hand side of $$F_X(t+\varepsilon)-F_X(t-\varepsilon)\leq 0$$ in terms of the probability of an event involving $X$?

Comment: @yurnero not sure what I can infer, it just mean that this inequality may be true, but not for sure

Comment: P.s. that was meant to be a hint, not a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
F_X(t+\epsilon) - F_X(t-\epsilon) = \mathbb{P}[X\in(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon]]\geq\mathbb{P}[X=t].
$$
Therefore, if $\mathbb{P}[X=t]>0$, then $F_X(t+\epsilon)-F_X(t-\epsilon)>0$, contradicting the given condition: $F_X(t+\varepsilon) \leq F_X(t-\varepsilon)$. So it must be that $\mathbb{P}[X=t]=0$.